# How to use one USB-C port between 2x ESP32-S3 - Switched by toggle switch?

Tags: arduino, transistors, usb, switches, esp32

I am trying to switch over a USB and it's associated Data +/- traces with a physical toggle switch.

I've tried to work out how to do it with just the switch, but I don't think that would work as it only has one physical pathway through the switch.

I've tried even harder to do it with transistors, but I'm finding their setup really complex to understand.

More Information

---

USB Receptacle is: https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_G-Switch-GT-USB-7010AO_C963413.html

Required speed is: USB 2.0 12Mbps

I know there are things like a DIP switch made up of individual switches I need the separate poles but with one slider. My trouble is trying to switch different circuits on or off.

Update:

The connections look good on the board view. The switch is routing the data to either CPU1 or CPU2.
If it looks alright, I will close the question as answered. Thanks

[image]

[image: What I'm currently working with]
[image: Updated Illustration]

Comment: Well it sure won't work through transistors. If you have problems switching through a switch, provide schematics how you switch it through a switch. Maybe that is not the problem but something else is. Also, USB is a high speed digital signal, not intended to pass through a mechanical switch. Why do you even need to switch two MCUs to a single USB connector? What is that grey box in the middle?

Comment: @Justme For going through just a switch I don't really know how other then to use 2 switches individually. I want to use just one port because it seems redundant to use 2 USB components for the same thing when they can be electronically switched. The final board will have to have only one USB also. The grey box in the middle is common 2 position switch sharing one pin in the middle.

Comment: I will add a picture to illustrate what I mean better. Give me a minute...

Comment: I have to switch at least 2 connections with one switch Is what I need a solution for.

Comment: I Don't know if there is some kind of a component I can add that has 4 or so separate channels that the switch can activate. One for each of the switch's states?

Comment: Is this for USB 2.0 (480-Mbps) speed? If so, there are some ICs such as [TS3USB221A ESD Protected, High-Speed USB 2.0 (480-Mbps) 1:2 Multiplexer and Demultiplexer Switch With Single Enable](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3usb221a.pdf)

Comment: @ChesterGillon Oh wow awesome. That looks suitable. I was wondering if there is some kind of universal approach for this thing that I don't know the name of. I also need to switch an SPI display between the 2x ESP32's - The display has about 5 pins

Comment: www.ti.com/lit/sg/scyt129e/scyt129e.pdf
is something like this component suitable to use separately for both the USB-C 2.0 & the Display?

Comment: @happycamper1221 Your illustration is even more confusing. What you must mean is one wire from USB to switch and from switch to either MCU A or B? Also what USB speed you need? USB3 or USB2? 5 Gbps, 480 Mbps, 12 Mbps, 1.5 Mbps? Can you show your real schematics how USB-C is connected? Do you need a switch or would a trick to flip USB-C connector suffice? Which USB-C receptacle you have?

Comment: @Justme USB 2.0. Yes that's what I mean

Comment: @happycamper1221 There's three USB 2.0 speeds. I asked which speed you require, among other things you did not provide an answer to help.

Comment: @Justme Sorry, speed is 480Mbps, schematic of what you requested is here https://imgur.com/a/7PDBZJA - the USB-C receptacle is https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_G-Switch-GT-USB-7010AO_C963413.html - I would prefer the toggle switch. I haven't seen that flip technique before thank you.

Comment: @happycamper1221 this site is not a chat forum ... all related information must be included within the question ... comments are not part of the question ... please update your question

Comment: There are toggle switches available with 2, 3, or 4 poles (they switch 2, 3, or 4 separate circuits)

Comment: @happycamper1221 I don't think that supports USB-HS 480 Mbps but only up to USB-FS 12 Mbps. Are you absolutely sure about 480 Mbps?

Comment: @happycamper1221 How are CC pins connected? You do see that the LED will never light up? Why is shield unconnected?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a cheap USB hub IC (like [this](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/USB2512B-M2?qs=uus7iwvxYD%252BUZYlM%252BHhqMA%3D%3D) one)? The USB bus is hub based and will mean that both downstream MCUs will be available to the host simultaneously on different addresses. No switching required.

From my experience, messing with the data lines on a high speed bus is a no-no. It MAY still work but you will cause yourself a debugging headache if things start to play up when you finish the design. There are some good documents out there on how to implement USB on circuit boards

Comment: The [MSP-EXP430F5529LP](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430F5529LP) is an example of a development board which contains a [TUSB2046](https://www.ti.com/product/TUSB2046B) _4-port USB 2.0 12-Mbps USB full-speed hub_ to make two downstream MCU available to the USB host. Albeit in this example the two MCUs are different.